# Dynamic Redirect via htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic, redirect

Hey, 
I wonder if you guys could help me with redirecting the following url:

```
http://mypage/index.php/some/thing?ax=ok&fb_comment_id=fbc_10150169233399496_16315207_10150170953264496
```

This is a url anybody will produce if somebody comments on the page "/some/thing?ax=ok". 
I would now redirect these kind of urls to:

```
http://mypage/index.php/some/thing?ax=ok
```

Well I thought that the best idea is to redirect every url which contains "fb_comment_id". 
But I can not directly redirect it to the mentioned url because there are multiple urls whhere users can leave a facebook comment. 
Therefore I'll have to find a way to cut off everything after "?ax=ok".

Is there a way to achive this in htaccess?
Help would be appreciated. 
Thanks Ripei

btw. Happy easter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question properly then following rule in your .htaccess will work fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ax=ok&fb_comment_id= [NC]
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?ax=ok [L,R,NE]
```

Above rule will **cut off everything after "?ax=ok"**

Comment: Yeah, that works perfectly. Thank you. I hope it's okay, if i ask here a further question: Because I would like to know if there is a way to replace "index.php" with another term?

Comment: @Ripel glad that it works out for you. I would suggest posting your question as a separate question with little more information and I will happily provide the answer for that too.

Comment: Just figured it out - wasnt that difficult: (and therefore I won't open an additional question): `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ax=ok&fb_comment_id= [NC]
RewriteRule . /anyTerm%{REQUEST_URI}?ax=ok [L,R,NE]` -> But I am already facing another rewriteruel-issue ;)

Comment: Glad to know that it worked out for you. Feel free to open a question for **another rewrite rule issue** :)

Comment: Seems like I've already troubles in spelling it correctly ;) Yes, thanks just opened it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index.php/([^\/]+)/([^\/]+)?ax=ok&fb_comment_id=.* index.php/$1/$2?ax=ok
```

Seems fairly straightforward.

Comment: Alright this looks pretty useful. Although I am asking myself if I am supposed to add this extra to each of the links. F.e. i could have a page: "index.php/some2/thing?ax=ok" or "index.php/not/thing?ax=ok"... and so on.

Comment: I've updated my solution. It should now match anything you put between index.php/ and /thing.etc...

Comment: I am so sorry for again having created confusion: I would prefer If "thing" could also be dynamic. I also tried your solution and I am afraid it does not work for me. Great page for testing purposes: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Comment: It won't work because RewriteRule doesn't match QUERY_STRING.